# multiple wait_for_messages wanted discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I am making a quiz and I want to be able to search through the answers and determine which message only has the artist in, which message only has the song name in, and which message says them both. I've made 3 check functions to show this however I want all 3 wait_for_message statements to run side by side. Any ideas on how this could be remedied?

```
await client.say("What is the song name and artist?")
def check1(msg):
    return name in msg.content.upper() and artist not in msg.content.upper()
def check2(msg):
    return artist in msg.content.upper() and name not in msg.content.upper()
def check3(msg):
    return name in msg.content.upper() and artist in msg.content.upper()
msg1 = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=10, check=check1)
msg2 = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=10, check=check2)
msg3 = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=20, check=check3)
if msg3 is not None:
   await client.say("@{} got both of them right! It was indeed {} by {}".format(msg3.author, toString(name), 
                                                                                     toString(artist)))
elif msg1 is not None and msg2 is not None:
        await client.say("@{} got the song name and @{} got the artist name! It was indeed {} by {}".format(msg1.author, 
                                                                           msg2.author, toString(name), toString(artist)))
elif msg1 is not None and msg2 is None:
        await client.say("@{} got the song name but no one got the artist! It was {} by {}".format(msg1.author,
                                                                                       toString(name), toString(artist)))
elif msg1 is None and msg2 is not None:
        await client.say("@{} got the artist name but no one got the song name! It was {} by {}".format(msg2.author,
                                                                                       toString(name), toString(artist)))
elif msg1 is None and msg2 is None and msg3 is None:
        await client.say("No one got it! It was {} by {}! Better luck next time".format(toString(name), toString(artist)))
```

Comment: take a look at the asyncio module

Comment: Instead, check for a message that matches any of those criteria, then classify it outside `wait_for_message`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I think he is waiting for all three so that if people guess just the name, someone else can still attempt to guess the artist or both together.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are looking for is [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). This lets you run multiple coroutines at the same time and wait until all methods are returned.

The return list from gather is in the order of the inputs, not in the order of task completion.

```
ret = await asyncio.gather(
    client.wait_for_message(timeout=10, check=check1),
    client.wait_for_message(timeout=10, check=check2),
    client.wait_for_message(timeout=10, check=check3)
)

msg1, msg2, msg3 = *ret
# msg1 has the name
# msg2 has the artist
# msg3 has both
```

Since the rewrite version of discord.py has `client.wait_for` throw an error instead of returning None, you can instead do this.

```
ret = await asyncio.gather(
    client.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check1),
    client.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check2),
    client.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check3),
    return_exceptions = True
)

# Test for errors
ret = [r if not isinstance(r, Exception) else None for r in ret]
msg1, msg2, msg3 = *ret
```