# Multiple wait_for messages discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

**What I'm trying to do**: This is a similar situation to [a question I previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592474/discord-py-messaging-multiple-people-at-the-same-time-and-receiving-their-inputs), I am making a multiplayer game. I wanted to get multiple user inputs at the same time, basically the situation in another question I had found ([multiple wait_for_messages wanted discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358080/multiple-wait-for-messages-wanted-discord-py)).

**My Problem**: I need to send messages to a different set of people each time. Basically, one game may have 3 players, while another might have 5 players. The original aim was also to send a message simultaneously to a user's dms and have them answer the input from there. I am unsure how to define the amount of `wait_for`s I need in my code.

**Code attempt 1**:

```py
    # inside a cog
    @commands.command()
    async def bagpie(self, ctx, *members: discord.Member):
        members = list(members)
        if ctx.author not in members:
            members.append(ctx.author)
        if len(members) > 3:
            return
        # making checks
        def check1(msg):
            return msg.author == members[0]
        def check2(msg):
            return msg.author == members[1]
        def check3(msg):
            return msg.author == members[2]      
        # waiting for multiple messages with the checks      
        ret = await asyncio.gather(
        await self.bot.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check1),
        await self.bot.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check2),
        await self.bot.wait_for("message", timeout=10, check=check3),
        return_exceptions = True
        )

        # Test for errors
        ret = [r if not isinstance(r, Exception) else None for r in ret]
        msg1, msg2, msg3 = ret # *ret would cause an error to occur
        # setup embed to send final product
        fin_string = ""
        count = 0
        msg_list = [msg1, msg2, msg3]
        for member in members:
            fin_string += f"{member} says: {msg_list[count]}"
            count += 1
        embed = discord.Embed(title="This is what you said!", description=fin_string)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Result: As you can see, despite there being inputs given, the bot does not respond and instead reverts to the timeout.

[image: Result of Attempt 1 not working]

**Code Attempt 2**:

```py
# couldn't get this to work in a cog, so this one is not in a cog

# checks if it's a dm and if author is given member
def is_dm_check(member):
    def inner_check(msg):
        return msg.author.id==member.id and msg.guild is None
    return inner_check

# sends message to member and waits for the message
async def get_input(member):
    await member.send("Please provide an input:")
    return client.wait_for('message', check=is_dm_check(member), timeout=75)

@client.command()
async def play_game(ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member]=None):
    if not members:
        await ctx.send("No Players")
        return
    if ctx.author not in members:
        members.append(ctx.author)
    responses = asyncio.gather(*map(get_input, members))
    for member, response in zip(members, responses):
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}: {response.content}")
```

Result: Messages were supposedly sent simultaneously, however it still throws an error.

[image: Code once again throws an error]

Comment: Have you tried to include a `while True` loop?

Comment: Are you aware that you’re missing a couple of `await `s here and there?

Comment: Instead of making three separate checks why don't you combine them in one? `def check(m): return msg.author in members`

Comment: @Dominik for which are you referring to? I could use a `while True` loop and loop through all the members, but that would not provide the simultaneous effect I would be hoping for.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'm not sure where I would be missing any `await`s, could you mention a few places I may be missing them?

Comment: `responses = asyncio.gather(*map(get_input, members))` and `return client.wait_for('message', check=is_dm_check(member), timeout=75)`

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński The three separate checks are to store the different inputs into a single variable, as you can probably see in my first attempt. The idea was to get the given input from each person simultaneously and saving it for later use

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Adding the awaits fixed the inputs! I believe my question has been answered, thank you